# Can't append Image at specific index of array and post with formdata through axios in react-native

Tags: php, react-native, file-upload, axios, multipartform-data

I'm using formdata to send images and content through axios in react-native.
[The response I want to send is something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6qvc.png).
If there are already two pictures present in Database, I insert image at index 2, leaving 0th and 1st index empty. Similarly if I have to update my Second image, I upload and push the image on 1st index.

When I test my api on postman, the image gets inserted in db. [Here is a screenshot of postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7N0f.png)

Now when I send my formdata through react native, It doesn't show up in db, although the image get saved to my uploads folder. Here is my react native code

```
if (self.state.imagesArray.length > 0){
      var count = self.state.images_key.length;

      self.state.imagesArray.forEach((image, i) => {

        var file = {
            uri : image.uri,
            type: image.type,
            name: image.name
        }  

        console.log(arr)
        formData.append(image[count], file)
        count= count + 1;
    });}
```

here imagesArray is the array where each uploaded file gets inserted at index 0,1 and so on.
images_key are the already present images in db. If there count is 2(for example), I will get image from imagesArray and append it in form at 2nd index index. But Image never shows up in db. When I do it in Postman, it shows!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved it.

```
self.state.imagesArray.forEach((image, i) => {

        var file = {
            uri : image.uri,
            type: image.type,
            name: image.name
        }  

        arr[count] = file;
        console.log(arr);
        formData.append("image["+count+"]", arr[count])
        count= count + 1;
    });
```